# Django ORM my ID growth non linear when save() data into model

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

In my django project i have a very strange behaviour from a model related to the Primary id field values in db.
I have this model:

```
class Results(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    proj_code = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    res_key = models.SlugField(max_length=80, verbose_name="Message unique key", unique=True)
    read_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Datetime of vals readings")
    unit = models.ForeignKey(ModbusDevice, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.device

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['device', 'unit', 'proj_code', 'read_date']),
        ]
```

well, in a .py file i save data into this table like this:

```
try:
    p = Results(device=Device.objects.get(mac_id=macid),
        proj_code=projid,
        res_key=datalist[x]['key'],
        read_date = topic_date,
        unit=unit_ck)

     p.save()
except IntegrityError as e:
     if 'UNIQUE constraint' not in e.args[0]:
         pass
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    pass
```

so, data where saved in db but if i inspect the "id" field i see strange behaviours like these:

```
|id|Others...
|1 |data
|2 |data
|3 |data
|11|data
|12|data
!99|data
```

My PostgreSql db field is setted like this pic:

[image]

I don't know why but my id does not growth linear as i expected.
Have someone  experienced the same behaviour?
How can i force save data with inear id growth?

So many thanks in advance
Manuel

Comment: What you are experiencing is gaps within your generated id. This **is not strange** behavior. It is *normal and expected*. Identity columns are implemented via `sequences` and once a value is used it will never be reused regardless of the result of that use. ( Never reused unless you specifically reset it.)

Comment: Thanks so mutch, how can i reset it and restore a linear increment behavior restarting from 1?

Comment: You can reset it with the [Alter Sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-altersequence.html) command. However, while this initially your unnecessary  increment behavior, but you ***cannot avoid gaps from developing***. That is by design being the only way guarantee uniqueness. Be ready to deal with the duplicate key errors as result of resetting the sequence. Best advice: accept gaps, get over it and move on.  (continued)

Comment: Generating gap less sequences you will need to: Create a table to hold the sequence. Single thread access to this table and any process that uses it. Use `update ... returning` for every use (probably in a trigger on the table(s)) . Accept the overall system performance desegregation as it because of single threading. Do not allow delete on the table(s) that use it. This will give a good change of getting a gap less "sequence" but not guaranteed. The only time I even attempt a gap less sequence is when there is a *legal requirement*. Again Best advice: accept gaps, get over it and move on.